Is it possible to change WooCommerce "Product description" title to custom text?
Weird question but couldn't find a way to overwrite any hook that is related to product description title. Is there a way to overwrite "Product description" and replace it with my own text? Thanks!


Try the code given below:
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'gs_admin_scripts', 20 );
function gs_admin_scripts(){
    wp_localize_script(
        'wc-admin-product-editor',
        'woocommerce_admin_product_editor',
        array(
            'i18n_description' => esc_js( __( 'My Custom Description Title is here', 'woocommerce' ) ),
        )
    );
}

Add the code in the child theme`s functions.php or your plugin.
The code has been tested and working.


There is no real need (apart from possible speed improvement) to check for the current screen if you localize the script that is meant for the product editor screen.

You can easily do like this example below (Tested and worked)
add_filter( 'gettext', 'your_prefix_change_product_description_title', 10, 2 );

function your_prefix_change_product_description_title( $alt, $text )
{
global $pagenow, $typenow;
if ('product' == $typenow ) {
if ( 'Product description' == $text ) {
return 'Your custom text';
}
}
return $alt;
}


Would work but what if WooCommerce gets translated then hardcoded string wouldn't work?

This solution only works when the text is not translated + it will also overwrite every other text that reads «  Product description » introducing food for bugs.

I have added the if condition, this is only work for backend and when the page is product

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
